# How to bring back drum roll sound in Ubuntu 17.10 when system is ready for user to log in

Tags: unity, sound, login, 17.10

In Ubuntu 16.04, when I powered on my computer, the drum roll sound would be played right before I was presented with the Login interface. After I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 the drum roll sound is no longer being played. I did some research on the web and tried the following, which enabled the drum roll sound to be played, but only after I had logged in.

I launched Startup Applications Preferences and added an item that contained the following.

```
/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" -f /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg
```

But this only enabled the sound to be played after I had already logged in.

I also tried

```
/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="system-ready" -f /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg
```

But that had the same effect as the other attempt; the drum roll sound played only after I had logged in.

So I am asking whether anyone has found a way to enable the drum roll sound to play before the user has logged in, when the user is presented with the login dialog.

I also tried --id="system-bootup" which should have brought up the drum roll sound much earlier.  But even with that setting, the drum roll sound was not played until after I logged in.

Comment: Changing to lightdm from gdm3 may solve this. Though the loging screen will look like 17.04-. apt install lightdm. dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

Comment: If we were to install and to use lightdm and if it didn't work, and if we wanted to go back to gdm3 how would we do that?  I suspect (without proof) that the issue we are seeing now with the drum roll is a (relatively-minor) bug with 17.10

Comment: apt purge lightdm, dpkg-reconfigure gdm3

Comment: lightdm depends on a bunch of packages which should be pushed away from xwayland, e.g. xserver-xorg*, unity*, etc. What are the gdm guys doing?

Comment: Please tell us if the answer worked for you Richard, so that then I can just put this bounty on it! **;-)**

Comment: There's a related [bug reported on gdm3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1736046), which has been confirmed. But it has not been fixed yet.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a way using a systemd user unit running from the gdm user's home directory.

- Save the following file as `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/systemd/user/drumroll.service`:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Drumroll
  Requires=pulseaudio.socket
  After=systemd-user-sessions.service

  [Service]
  Type=simple
  Restart=no
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg

  [Install]
  WantedBy=default.target
  ```

The above systemd unit should make sure that pulseaudio has been started in the gdm user context and execute the [`paplay`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/paplay.1.html) command (I haven't tried `canberra-gtk-play`, but I would think it works as well).

`After=systemd-user-sessions.service` will make the service start only after the system is ready for user logins. (see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man8/systemd-user-sessions.service.8.html)

- Then execute:

  ```
  $ sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/gdm3/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants
  $ sudo ln -s /var/lib/gdm3/.config/systemd/user/drumroll.service /var/lib/gdm3/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/drumroll.service
  $ sudo chown gdm:gdm /var/lib/gdm3/.config/systemd/user/{drumroll.service,default.target.wants}
  ```

Those last commands make the unit start automatically when the systemd session of the gdm user is started.

- Reboot to test.

To check for errors is a little bit tricky, because systemctl has the restriction to connect to either the system session or the *calling user's* session. To make gdm the calling user is easy with sudo, but some environment needs to be set up to make it possible to connect to its systemd user session:

```
$ sudo -u gdm XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$(id -u gdm)" DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus" systemctl --user status drumroll
● drumroll.service - Drumroll
   Loaded: loaded (/var/lib/gdm3/.config/systemd/user/drumroll.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2018-06-26 23:35:05 CEST; 36min ago
  Process: 1238 ExecStart=/usr/bin/paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
 Main PID: 1238 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I haven't tried this with 17.10, but 18.04, but I don't see a reason it wouldn't work as well on 17.10.

Comment: Quicker than me!  +1!

Comment: I'm also sure it would work with 17.10. It's obsolete next month so OP will be upgrading to 18.04 soon anyway. +1.